# Maps v2 tint a Marker

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to get `Marker` tinted using Google Maps v2. Following solution is not working:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
d.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(
    R.color.tint_color), Mode.MULTIPLY);
BitmapDescriptor bitmap = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap());
myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(bitmap).position(latLon));
```

Is there alternative solution to get `Markers`tinted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're tinting the drawable (changing its paint, really) but you're then passing the underlying Bitmap. One way to fix this outside the Maps API (with which I'm unfamiliar) is to draw the Drawable to a Canvas with a new Bitmap.

```
Bitmap filtered = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getBitmap());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(filtered);
d.draw(canvas);
```

(This is just an example, it's not doing any error handling - you should handle the case when Android gives you back the same Bitmap instead of a new one. It's also not handling bounds)

Comment: I tried your answer, but the first line is wrong straight away. I get the code error hint "cannot resolve method getBitmap()". Can you provide a fuller explanation?